# Does converting .mp4 to .mkv change data fidelity?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am wondering when I convert a `.mp4` to `.mkv` using the following command if the quality changes.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 out.mkv
```

The input file, `in.mp4` has a file size of 297 megabytes, while the `out.mkv` file has a size of *249 megabytes*, ~15% lower. Upon manual inspection, the resolution, video, and audio streams are the same before/after (as I would have expected given my (limited) knowledge of ffmpeg).

Is the 15% size decrease by simply converting to `mkv` actually not affect the quality of the video? If so this seems like a very reasonable way of freeing up some space on my computer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The quality gets worse

This is due to [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss) because you are re-encoding the video and audio to lossy formats. But you may not notice the difference.

The output file size will vary depending on the input format, if it was encoded well or badly, your output format, and the settings you use.

## MP4 to MKV without quality loss

You can just re-mux and avoid re-encoding by using [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mkv
```

You can think of it like a copy and paste. The video and audio is untouched and just put into a new container.

Comment: I know it's an old question but, what if the MP4 has subtitles in it?  While the above worked, with a quick conversion, VLC sees a subtitle track in the original MP4 that doesn't exist in the new MKV.

Comment: I poked around and it looks like subtitles can be a bit of a wildcard.  Is this true?  I was playing around and found that the following bit of code seems to grab anything found in the MP4 however, again, it didn't grab the subtitle track: `ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "My Movie.mp4" -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v? -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy "My Movie.mkv"`